# How to call code behind C# function from javascript or jquery which is in different project

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two projects in my solution : Presentation and CommonControls.

I need to call a function defined in a class inside CommonControls. But this call has to be from the javascript function defined in Presentation which is a common javascript file for Presentation project.

Both the files are in different project.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: It might be the case. But can you explain me this :
1. if I have to write JaveScript function not on page but to a common js file can I still use PageMethods?

Comment: I know all of you think this is duplicate question. But in my case both the files are in different projects. Please read the question correctly.